# How big a single Azure Function can be?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My Azure Function will require resources to run properly (ranging from 5 to 30 Mb). I'm thinking of putting them on the Blob Storage and loading from the Storage each time function runs, but since it will be quite often (a couple times per day) I'm thinking of simply putting them as resources in the function project.

The question is, how much space can I allocate for the function itself? How big (in terms of disk space) a Azure Function can be?

Comment: You can checkout Platform features -> App Service plan -> File system storage -> Threshold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on which host plan your Function app is on.

For dedicate App service plan(Pricing tier Basic, Standard and so on), we can see the size of disk storage allocated for this plan. 
Just like @Slava Utesinov has mentioned, we can also check it from `Platform features -> App Service plan -> File system storage` as well.
[image: size disk]

For Consumption plan, File system storage shows 0KB usage among 1GB available. Because Function apps on Consumption plan are stored in Storage File Share, which is specified by `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` Application settings on Azure portal, check [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#websitecontentazurefileconnectionstring). As for space, max size of a File share is 5TB, see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets#azure-files-scale-targets).

Comment: It seems like even in basic plans my 30 Mb will be a drop in the ocean - definitely worth putting inside the Function project. Thanks!